# Приведение функции к типу bool

Tags: c++

Нашёл в исходнике непонятный код:

```
if (foo)
    foo();
```

, где foo - объект типа `std::function<void()>`.

Для чего может понадобится такое приведение к `bool`, и когда функция не будет вызываться?

Comment: @Igor, таки это приведение к `bool`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если эту проверку убрать, то может получится так, что в переменной `foo` ранее не была сохранена функция, и при попытке вызова оной будет выброшено исключение [`std::bad_function_call`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bad_function_call).

Подобная проверка является стандартной практикой, если переменная типа `std::function` не инициализируется в месте создания и может быть пустой.

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать. Пришлось покопаться в реализации, т.к. пытаюсь словить один гадкий баг :-)

Answer (score 2):

В данном фрагменте кода имеет место не приведение, а вызов оператора `operator bool()`.

Что именно будет делать та или иная его перегрузка — каким-то образом преобразовывать переданное значение к `bool` или возвращать флаг некоего внутреннего состояния — определяет исключительно автор этой перегрузки.

В случае с `std::function<T>` данный оператор:

> проверяет, что экземпляр хранит не пустое значение.
>
> *http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator_bool*

Comment: А «вызов оператора operator bool()» это не приведение?

Comment: @ixSci, приведение типа — это преобразование представления без изменения его смысла (по крайней мере, как это понимаю я). К примеру, было «`0` — ложь, остальное —  истина», стало «`false` — ложь, `true` — истина». Здесь же несколько иной случай, так как ***тип нетривиальный***. Булево значения имеет иной смысл, чем данные класса; с таким же успехом мы могли бы возвращать, к примеру, факт использования нестандартного аллокатора.

Comment: Тут нет смысла рассуждать, с  точки зрения стандарта есть 2 понятия: cast и conversion; cast приводит к conversion. `operator bool()` в `std::function` является explicit cast к `bool`; результатом выполнения этого оператора является _преобразование_ типа `std::function` в `bool`. Семантика самого преобразования совершенно не важна.

Answer (score 1):

Перед вызовом функции, заданной через переменную типа `std::function<T>`, стоит проверять, что она была ранее установлена, в противном случае, при попытке вызвать ее будет сгенерировано исключение.

Для предотвращения данного сценария в `std::function` реализован оператор приведения к булеву типу `operator bool()`, который вернет `true`, если экземпляр хранит не пустое значение.

Такая проверка часто используется перед вызовом каллбеков (обратных вызовов) или делегатов.

Ниже приведен пример использования:

```
void MyClass {
// ...
private:
    std::function<void()> _onEventCallback { nullptr };
};    

void MyClass::SetOnEventCallback(const std::function<void()>& cb)
{
    _onEventCallback = cb;
}

void MyClass::EventHandler()
{
    if (_onEventCallback)
    {
        _onEventCallback();
    }
}
```

В классе `MyClass` приватное поле `_onEventCallback` инициализируется значением `nullptr` при создании экземпляра класса. Клиентский код может выставить данный каллбек через публичный интерфейс класса - метод `SetOnEventCallback`.

Таким образом мы устанавливаем обработчик события, который будет вызван при наступлении определенных условий (в момент вызова `MyClass::EventHandler`).

С другой стороны, не все экземпляры класса `MyClass` должны реагировать на наступление данного события (простым примером может быть биндинг обработчиков клавиатурных клавиш. На определенные клавиши навешивается обработчики, на другие - нет)

Comment: Да, функция действительно называется `callback`

Comment: Да, это нормальная практика. Ты, например, можешь задать callback на событие возврата данных с сервера от какой-нибудь команды или на клик правой клавиши мыши, на событие системного таймера.. Все, что угодно. Но не каждое событие нужно обрабатывать. Поэтому его и нужно проверять на nullptr